# Default Form Button in FireFox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building a server control that will search our db and return results.  The server control is contains an ASP:Panel.  I have set the default button on the panel equal to my button id and have set the form default button equal to my button id.

On the Panel:

```
 MyPanel.DefaultButton = SearchButton.ID
```

On the Control:

```
Me.Page.Form.DefaultButton = SearchButton.UniqueID
```

Works fine in IE & Safari I can type a search term and hit the enter key and it searches fine.  If I do it in Firefox I get an alert box saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an a object.

Anyone run across this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ends up this resolved my issue:

```
     SearchButton.UseSubmitBehavior = False
```

Answer (score 3):

Is SearchButton a LinkButton?  If so, the javascript that is written to the browser doesn't work properly.

Here is a good blog post explaining the issue and how to solve it:

[Using Panel.DefaultButton property with LinkButton control in ASP.NET](http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/using-panel-defaultbutton-property-with-linkbutton-control-in-asp-net/)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong and this might not make a difference but have you tried:

```
Me.Page.Form.DefaultButton = SearchButton.ID
```

instead of

```
Me.Page.Form.DefaultButton = SearchButton.UniqueID
```